Why doesn't Netgear download “client.key” or “ca.cert” in the OpenVPN configuration package download button for Windows?
When I click to download the configuration package for OpenVPN, Netgear only downloads the OVPN file which contains no key or ca.cert. On other device I download 3-4 files but this one has no other files and OpenVPN doesn't connect with the provided config file.
Log file states:
Options error: --ca fails with 'ca.crt': The system cannot find the file specified.   (errno=2)
Options error: --cert fails with 'client.crt': The system cannot find the file specified.   (errno=2)
2024-09-22 19:52:36 WARNING: cannot stat file 'client.key': The system cannot find the file specified.   (errno=2)
Options error: --key fails with 'client.key': The system cannot find the file specified.   (errno=2)
Options error: Please correct these errors.
Use --help for more information.

The OVPN file is as follows:
client
dev tap
proto udp
sndbuf 393216
rcvbuf 393216
push "sndbuf 393216"
push "rcvbuf 393216"
dev-node NETGEAR-VPN
remote redacted.mynetgear.com 12974
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client.crt
key client.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
verb 0

I have tried updating the firmware and openvpn_crt_check.htm. Not sure where to go from here. Just trying to do basic setup.
